# Finding row number of text?

Tags: python

Currently, I am working with a big set of data and I need find the number of the row that says `<event>`. There are many events and I need the data of the row below this text. I tried doing this with a simple for loop, but it did not work. I am not entirely sure how to properly divide the text into lines and to find when a certain line says exactly `<event>`.

This is the code I tried:

```py
file_read=open('/path/to/myfile.lhe', 'r')

for line in enumerate(file_read):
    if line == '<event>':
        print("line:",file_read[line])
```

This roughly resembles the data that I am working with. In this case I need to work with the data that is 1 line below `<event>`

```
< event>

15      1 +1.1944823e-05 8.30300200e+02 7.81860800e-03 9.63053500e-02

4.7000000000e+00 0.0000e+00 1.0000e+00
```

Comment: Is it `< event>`, `< events>`, `<event>`, or `<events>`, because you name all four of them and they are different things? Also note that there is always a trailing newline `\n` if you iterate through the lines like that, so `line == '<event>'` can never be `True`.

Comment: It is <event>, but for some reason the editor of Stackoverflow makes it disappear when it is written like that. But, for clarification, I always mean that there is a line that only says '<event>'.

Comment: You need to [use backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) to mark it as code, otherwise it will be interpreted as inline HTML (I fixed it).

Comment: For future posts, better don't use real paths, replace them with a fake path, and please remove commented lines and other things that are irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable to know whether or not you should perform an action on the next row like this:

```
file_read=open('/home/steven/Downloads/MG5_aMC_v3_4_0/APP_2022/Signal/Events/Test1/unweighted_events.lhe', 'r')

#print(file_read.read())

trigger = False
for line in enumerate(file_read):
    if trigger:
       trigger = False
       # do stuff here

    if line == '<event>':
       trigger = True
       print("line:",file_read[line])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

iter_lines = iter(lines)

for line in iter_lines:
    if '<event>' in line:
        print(next(iter_lines))
```

Comment: Forget my previous comment, I see what you're doing now. Mind adding some explanation?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This one works and it works perfectly, thank you so much mate!

Answer (score 0):

#One approach is save index on an array where the string value is found
file_read='/home/steven/Downloads/MG5_aMC_v3_4_0/APP_2022/Signal/Event/Test1/unweighted_events.lhe'

```
cb = []
index = 0
for word in file_read.split("/"):
    index+=1
    print(word)
    if word.lower() == 'event':
      cb.append(index)
      print("Found:",word," at:",index)
```